# How to get data from spring beans class?

Tags: spring

I am developing a web application for that have created a bean class where all setter and getter method exist like:

```
private String LeaveType;
private String leavePeriod;

private String reason;
private String FirstApprover;

private String finalApprover;
private String selectHours;

public String getLeaveType() {
    return LeaveType;
}

public void setLeaveType(String leaveType) {
    LeaveType = leaveType;
}

public String getLeavePeriod() {
    return leavePeriod;
}

public void setLeavePeriod(String leavePeriod) {
    this.leavePeriod = leavePeriod;
}

public String getReason() {
    return reason;
}

public void setReason(String reason) {
    this.reason = reason;
}

public String getFirstApprover() {
    return FirstApprover;
}

public void setFirstApprover(String firstApprover) {
    FirstApprover = firstApprover;
}

public String getFinalApprover() {
    return finalApprover;
}

public void setFinalApprover(String finalApprover) {
    this.finalApprover = finalApprover;
}

public String getSelectHours() {
    return selectHours;
}

public void setSelectHours(String selectHours) {
    this.selectHours = selectHours;
}
```

In above class the details from the html page gets saved temprory when click ob submit that data I want to fetch it in my another controller class by creating object of that class rather than fetching it from database, and I have tried but getting null values so,Is there any way to get out of this issue.
cotrooler class:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/leaveapplyform", method = RequestMethod.GET)
       public String showForm(ModelMap model,HttpServletRequest request) 
       {
         log.info("Inside Controller returning to leaveapplyform page....");

         LeaveApplyForm leaveapplyform =  new LeaveApplyForm();
        model.put("leaveapplyform", leaveapplyform);    


    return GlobalConstants.LEAVE_APPLY; 
       }


@RequestMapping(value = "/leaveapplyform" ,method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processForm(@ModelAttribute("leaveapplyform") LeaveApplyForm leaveapplyform,HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, ModelMap model)
    {
        leaveapplyform = (LeaveApplyForm) model.get("leaveapplyform");
System.out.println(leaveapplyform.getReason());//Here goes wrong

}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible slution would be to use Flash attributes (if you are using a version of Spring MVC >= 3.1). So you change your first `showForm` method to the following:

```
    public String showForm(@ModelAttribute("leaveapplyform")LeaveApplyForm leaveapplyform, HttpServletRequest request, final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
            log.info("Inside Controller returning to leaveapplyform page....");

            LeaveApplyForm leaveapplyform = new LeaveApplyForm();
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("leaveapplyform", leaveapplyform);

            return GlobalConstants.LEAVE_APPLY;
    }
```

And then in your `processForm` you access directly  the argument `leaveapplyform`, it shouldn't be null